# Find edges via Canny algorithm in timeseries(data array) via OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, filtering, signal-processing, canny-operator

like demonstrated here: http://www.cs.unc.edu/~nanowork/cismm/download/edgedetector/#application

I'd like to find the edges in a timeseries merely consisting of x and the related y-value.

I think the canny-algorithm might be a good solution for this task. I'd like to use OpenCv canny for this solution. So far my code looks like this:

```
import cv2

numpyarr = np.asarray(vals) # vals is like : [[0,29.8],[1,23.44]....]

img = cv2.imdecode(numpyarr, 0)

edges = cv2.Canny(img, 100, 200)

numpyedged = cv2.imencode(img,0)
```

As a result I'd like to have an array filled with the found edges like visualized in the link above.

Thanks very much.